# Reading Google Calendar recurring events using .Net API

Tags: c#, .net, api, google-calendar-api

I am doing some sync across different calendar formats and one of the Calendar providers is Google, Other providers expose this data in an object oriented approach through their API but in Google it is exposed via Events.Recurrence as this:

```
"DTSTART;TZID=Pacific/Auckland:20110629T100000\r\n
DTEND;TZID=Pacific/Auckland:20110629T110000\r\n
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=10;INTERVAL=3\r\n
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\r\n
TZID:Pacific/Auckland\r\n
X-LIC-LOCATION:Pacific/Auckland\r\n
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT\r\n
TZOFFSETFROM:+1200\r\n
TZOFFSETTO:+1300\r\n
TZNAME:NZDT\r\n
DTSTART:19700927T020000\r\n
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=9;BYDAY=-1SU\r\n
END:DAYLIGHT\r\n
BEGIN:STANDARD\r\n
TZOFFSETFROM:+1300\r\n
TZOFFSETTO:+1200\r\n
TZNAME:NZST\r\n
DTSTART:19700405T030000\r\n
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=4;BYDAY=1SU\r\n
END:STANDARD\r\n
END:VTIMEZONE"
```

Is there any way of parsing this to an object oriented format? 
i.e. a Recurrence object?
All of the samples I saw online are setting those values which is easier rather than reading it. Any samples of reading and writing to it are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

EventEntry.Times is a collection, so you have to parse it into an ExtensionCollection object, which you can then iterate through.

```
foreach (Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry ev in calFeed.Entries)
    {
        CalendarEvents ce = new CalendarEvents();

        ce.Title = ev.Title.Text;
        ExtensionCollection<When> v = ev.Times;
        ce.Date = v[0].StartTime;
        ce.Content = ev.Content.Content;
    }
```

Iterating wasn't necessary in my project, but i think you get the idea.

Comment: Will check this soon, will let you know what happens

Comment: I dont know why you give a solution for EventEntry.Times if Raymund ask you for the Event.Recurrence object... i also need the solution for the Recurrence object and get a .net datetime value.

Comment: good point, i don't know how i missed that. Since it'e one big string, i'd say you have to/shold make your own class with a bunch of parameters, and a single method returning all those strings in the correct format for the recurrence string

Answer (score 1):

Try this library: http://icalparser.sourceforge.net/